# Is the continuum hypothesis independent of ALL sensible models of arithmetic?

Tags: logic, set-theory

> Is the continuum hypothesis independent of ALL sensible models of arithmetic?

In [this post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/models-of-set-theory-with-same-reals-and-same-cardinals-but-which-disagree-on-ch/) Joel Hamkins shows that even if ZFC is consistent, it has two models which share the same cardinals, the same real numbers, and yet in one, CH is true and in the other CH is false.

In fact, he goes on, this can be forced in *any* model of ZFC.

Since ZFC models arithmetic, and all models of ZFC have a set-forcing extensions in which CH is both true and false, does this not imply that CH is effectively independent of ALL sensible models of arithmetic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This is just an addendum to Asaf's answer, and an elaboration on his comments below that answer; but it's a bit too long for a comment.*

First, let's clarify some things:

- ZFC is a *theory*, the same sort of object as Peano arithmetic PA. That is, it is a collection of sentences, which can be used to prove other sentences. It is distinct from its collection of *models*: just like there are many different groups (= models of the theory of groups), there are many different models of ZFC (assuming it's consistent!). In particular, your title isn't really asking what you want to.
- We thus have two different sides to ZFC: the *syntactic* (formulas and proofs) and the *semantic* (models). (Incidentally, these two sides are connected by the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).) On the semantic side, we are interested in methods for building models of ZFC, and in particular building new models from old ones. **This is what forcing does**, and for example we can use forcing to show that if ZFC has a model, then so does ZFC + CH, and also so does ZFC + $\neg$CH; by soundness, this means that ZFC doesn't prove CH or $\neg$CH. And forcing has lots of other applications besides.
- Now, what you're asking about is the *arithmetic consequences* of some *specific sentences*. To phrase this question precisely, we need three pieces:

  - **What does "arithmetic" mean?** The natural choice here is to look at sentences of the form "$\mathbb{N}=(\mathbb{N}; +,\times, 0, 1, <)$ satisfies $\varphi$" for $\varphi$ a first-order sentence in the language of arithmetic, and this is what I assume you mean; but note that there are other possibilities, e.g. looking at second- or higher-order choices of $\varphi$. For instance, $\neg$CH implies "There is a nonconstructible real," which is a *second-order* sentence about $\mathbb{N}$.
  - **What specific sentences do we care about?** Well, CH and $\neg$CH. Nothing to see here.
  - Finally, the important one: **what is our *background theory*?** That is, when we ask "What arithmetic consequences does CH have?", we don't mean CH in isolation, but CH *together with some "base theory"*. The base theory matters: there are lots of natural instances of sentences $\varphi,\psi$ where $\varphi\implies\psi$ is provable in ZFC but not in ZF, for example. In such a case would we say that $\psi$ is a consequence of $\varphi$? Well, obviously that depends on what base theory we're using!

So let's assume that I've got "arithmetic" correctly - you're interested in what we can prove about what first-order sentences the structure $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies. So all that's left is the choice of base theory.

If our base theory is ZFC, then **neither CH nor $\neg$CH have any arithmetical consequences apart from those of ZF itself**; formally, if ZFC+CH proves "$\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $\varphi$" for some first-order sentence $\varphi$, then already ZFC proves "$\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $\varphi$". And similarly for $\neg$CH.

The proof of this has two parts: forcing, and absoluteness. By forcing, from a model $M$ of ZFC (that is, from the assumption that ZFC is consistent - this equivocation uses the completeness theorem) we can construct a model $M'$ of ZFC+CH with the same constructible universe. In particular, these models agree on what first-order sentences (their versions of) $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies. By Shoenfield absoluteness *(actually much less is needed - even Mostowski absoluteness is overkill, as is the observation that $M$ and $M'$ have the same constructible universe - but whatever)*, $M$ itself thinks that (its version of) $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies these same first-order sentences. So any arithmetic consequence of ZFC+CH is already an arithmetic consequence of ZFC. And the situation is identical with $\neg$CH.

Of course, this is dependent on the choice of ZFC as our base theory. E.g. clearly CH has new arithmetic consequences over the theory ZFC+"CH implies Con(ZFC)". But this is of course a stupid alternate base theory, so this raises the question: *when can we extend the observation above to different theories, either stronger or weaker?* (Note that this gets to the "any reasonable" aspect of your question.)

The most straightforward approach to this question is to try to follow the argument above with ZFC replaced by a different theory; and this amounts to developing forcing and absoluteness results for that theory in place of ZFC. For natural set theories, the former is the key ingredient: if $T$ is a natural set theory, then $T$ contains a set corresponding to the natural numbers, and can develop semantics for this structure (in the same way that ZFC can express things like "$\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the Goldbach conjecture"). Now, forcing doesn't change either of these pieces, so we automatically have the absoluteness we need; so it all comes down to whether $T$ is preserved by forcing, or at least under the forcings we care about here. The extent to which different set theories are preserved under different kinds of forcings has been extensively studied, but is also extremely hard; I'll just mention here that the vastly weaker theory KP + Infinity + Powerset is known to be preserved by forcing, so neither CH and $\neg$CH have arithmetic consequences over this theory. (We need Inf + "$\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\omega))$ exists" to even talk about CH/$\neg$CH in a meaningful way in the theory.)

---

**Note that this sidesteps entirely the *philosophical question* of whether this means that CH is "ungrounded" in any sense, since that's really a different kind of investigation. For what it's worth, I would argue that there are degrees of groundedness, and that CH is much *less* grounded than e.g. the Riemann hypothesis, but that's just my opinion.**

Comment: I think you should consider collecting your answers on this site into a book. Folks like me not seriously interested in logic would enjoy browsing (since you  write so well). You could begin with a web page that collects your postings and classifies them with various attributes - something like a visible tag system local to logic.In a book you could combine answers that are closely related. You'd still want lots of cross references (hyperlinks).

Comment: Thanks, a fabulous answer once again.

Comment: I totally agree with @EthanBolker! Folks like me who are interested in logic **also** enjoy reading your answers. =) Like I didn't know that adding CH over ZFC is conservative for arithmetical sentences. Also, I would like to ask two things: (1) The question asks about models with the "same real numbers", but then CH is decided since the cardinality of the reals would be fixed. If so, the question as stated is wrong. (2) I am very interested to hear your philosophical view on groundedness of CH, perhaps at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the arithmetical truth using forcing, since you cannot change the basic structure of the ordinals using forcing. In fact, any two models with the same $\omega$ (which include all "sensible models", I believe) agree on the first-order theory of $\Bbb N$.

This extends slightly to second-order statement, $\Sigma^1_1$ and $\Pi^1_1$ in general for transitive models (Mostowski's absoluteness), and $\Sigma^1_2$ and $\Pi^1_2$ statements when it concerns forcing (Shoenfield's absoluteness).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was asking whether forcing *measures* the arithmetical truth rather than *changes* it. Is this a misconception on my part?

Comment: I don't know what that would even mean, for forcing to measure arithmetical truth...

Comment: what I mean by *measuring* the truth is... I'm trying to understand what you mean when you say forcing cannot "change arithmetical truth" since I thought I was only **making an inquiry into** the truth and hadn't considered any possibility of **changing** the truth... if that makes sense.

Comment: I **think** you mean, nothing which is true or false without forcing, is the opposite with forcing

Comment: It means that if an arithmetic statement is true, then it is true in all forcing extensions as well.

Comment: ...and if it is false then is it false in all forcing extensions as well?  And if it is independent, is it independent in all forcing extensions too?

Comment: If it is false, its negation is true. As for independent, you're mixing true and provable. But the answer is yes, since that would be an arithmetic statement (if I guess your intentions correctly).

Comment: Is it not an important result, that CH is independent of all models of arithmetic?

Comment: Independent from *what*? You ask a question using technical words, and I feel that you're not fully aware of their meaning.

Comment: Let's not. I am not the biggest fan of the chat feature.

Comment: Well I'm certainly not *fully* aware of their meaning, but I have some notion.  But the independence of CH from arithmetic in all reasonable models seems to me, in my limited non-technical understanding to be equivalent to Saul Kripke's notion that CH is an ungrounded statement. But your observation that I don't grasp various meanings rigorously is well-founded.

Comment: CH is a set theoretic statement. How do you even interpret it in models of arithmetic, e.g. in the natural numbers?

Comment: I think of ZFC as a model of arithmetic, which we use pretty much exclusively to study the properties of what results of arithmetic are, and are not, possible. While ZFC goes further, e.g. it can make statements about infinity with which we can make deductions about arithmetic which cannot be made in arithmetic alone, there are other statements makeable in models of arithmetic such as ZFC, which have no capacity to speak about what is and isn't possible in arithmetic. I'm interpreting this result as saying CH says nothing useful about arithmetic since it is independent from it in all models.

Comment: But I fully accept that any part of my understanding may be wrong.

Comment: No. ZFC is a list of axioms for sets. It has a natural interpretation for the axioms of arithmetic, and therefore can be used to study in some sense arithmetic. But it certainly not a model for arithmetic, just like arithmetic is not a way to model the notion of 0.

Comment: @RobertFrost "Well I'm certainly not fully aware of their meaning, but I have some notion" This might summarize in one sentence why your successive forays into various domains of mathematics which you do not "fully" understand (formerly probability, now logic, it seems), are not very... productive, shall we put it? All in all, *there is no substitute to learning a subject*.

Comment: @Did that's what I'm doing.